# How to prepend an element to an array in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

The Powershell code:

```
$list += "aa"
```

appends the element "aa" to the list $list. Is there a way to prepend an element? This is my solution, but there must be a way to do this in a single line.

```
$tmp = ,"aa";
$tmp += $list
$list = $tmp
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In your example above, you should just be able to do:

```
$list = ,"aa" + $list
```

That will simply prepend "aa" to the list and make it the 0th element.  Verify by getting `$list[0]`.

Comment: Technically, this combines two arrays. The array is of fixed size so a pure prepend is not possible.

Answer (score 23):

This combines two arrays into one.

```
$list = @("aa") + $list
```

It's impossible to do a pure prepending into a PowerShell array, because PowerShell arrays are fixed length. Combining two arrays into one is a good approach.

Comment: I like this answer, it's readable, it's intention is pretty clear!

Answer (score 18):

Using `+=` and `+` on arrays in PowerShell is making a copy of the array every time you use it.  That is fine unless the list/array is really large.  In that case, consider using a generic list:

```
C:\> $list = new-object 'System.Collections.Generic.List[string]'
C:\> $list.Add('a')
C:\> $list.Add('b')
C:\> $list.Insert(0,'aa')
C:\> $list
aa
a
b
```

Note that in this scenario you need to use the Add/Insert methods.  If you fall back to using `+=`, it will copy the generic list back to an `object[]`.

Comment: Note, your first $list will return an array of 2 elements. First element is 'aa', and second element is a nested list of 2 elements, 'a' and 'b'

Comment: I am not sure why this answer isn't voted up enough times. For things like log processing, this will win over simple concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to want to do this to an 'Object' array rather than a 'String', I found the following useful:

```
$List = $List | foreach {'aa' + $_}
```

Obviously, this would be relatively slow for a gigantic array.